# GETH "nodiscover " and addPeer behaviour

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js

I built a database with Ethereum node addresses.  Now I'm trying to add some of those nodes to my GETH node.

Problems that I'm experiencing:

- I'm initializing the geth node with --nodiscover.  My expected behaviour is for the GETH node NOT to add any peers or receive blocks.  This in fact is not happening.  It starts to connect with nodes before I'm manually adding nodes.
- When adding nodes through addPeer(), the nodes are added as 'static'.  They never end up being nodes used.  Even if I add 500 nodes, the network slowly adds node as if it was disovering them.  There is no difference is node accumulation speed between synching normally (self discovery) or using --nodiscover with addPeer().

Any idea why I'm seeing this behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

yes, it is retrieving peers from your previous sessions from local database.

use --maxpeers=0

you can also try to drop peers from the console